# GOC allylic,vinylic, benzylic positions, carbocation stability

Tags: organic-chemistry

Carbo-cations may be stabilized by:
(a) π-bonds only at allylic position

(b) π-bonds only at vinylic position

(c) π-bonds at allylic and benzylic position also
(d) -I effect

While the answer is obviously not (d), I am really confused about what 'allylic', 'vinylic' and 'benzylic' positions actually mean. I have heard about allylic/vinylic/benzylic carbons, but positions..?
Please, help.
Thank-you.

The question has been taken from ADVANCED PROBLEMS IN ORGANIC CHEMISTRY by HIMANSHU PANDEY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [allylic position explanation](http://web.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/A/allylic_position.html)
- [benzylic position explanation](http://web.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/B/benzylic_position.html)
- [vinylic position explanation](http://web.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/V/vinylic_position.html)

For carbocation stability, think about which case has opportunity for electron resonance, i.e., which case(s) allows the positive charge to be delocalized to adjacent pi bonds. This [resource](http://web.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/tutorials/cc.pdf) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Allylic position is the same as allylic carbon....similarly for vinylic and benzylic...so the stability of carbocations goes as

benzylic > allylic > vinylic
vinyl carbocations moreover are highly unstable...whereas the other two are rather stable ones...and the answer is (C) [image]
[image]